# Compare File Versions With Batch Script

Tags: ms-access, batch-file, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I've created an Access database to be shared through the entire department, which I've split into a front end and a back end. Unfortunately, there's no easy way I can figure out to ensure all users are consistently using the newest version of the front end on their local machine as I add requested updates.

To overcome this, I created an install batch script that creates a shortcut on their desktop. as well as nesting the front end and an "update" batch script in a custom folder on their PC. The shortcut actually links to the "update" batch script, which then downloads the newest version of the front end (overwriting the existing one), then loads it.

Ideally, this would not download it every time and instead only downloads it if the version of the front end on the network is greater than that on the local machine. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to do this with an accdb file (though I've seen information for executable files). We are using Access 2010 and an Access 2007 filetype. I still have not figured out how to append a version number to the front end, but I'm open to including a text file as well simply to store that version number. Any suggestions?

Below is the script I currently have for the update file.

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
XCOPY "\\NetworkPath\Install\*.accdb" c:\Reserved\Database /y /q
XCOPY "\\NetworkPath\Install\Update.bat" c:\Reserved\Database /y /q
CLS
ECHO Starting database...
START "" "C:\Reserved\Database\FrontEnd.accdb"
```

Comment: That sounds remarkably similar to something we implemented for a couple shared access databases.  However, I believe our script just copies it fresh every single time, as our users tend to leave the database open for long periods of time.  If I were to implement this, I would probably favor the text file idea, because even just opening a shared .accdb to check a "Versions table" has the potential to cause problems.

Comment: I always just had a one row table in the front end, and a one row table in the back end. In that table are things like area code defaults etc. And of course a version number. So you launch the app first, if version numbers are miss matched, you THEN shell out to the batch file and exit Access. The bat file thus copies over the front end and re-launches it. A "ok" prompt in the bat file tends to give "more" then enough time for the front end to exit/shut down. This approach means you launch Access and not a the bat file or script to update/copy.

Comment: Not a bad idea. So you basically write a macro or a script in vba to run upon the database starting that compares version numbers and launch a batch script (likely with a timeout) and closes that updates, and relaunches access?

Comment: Why not place a version number in a local front end table, and then in the back end have a version number. Set your shortcut to launch the main application (FE). In your startup code check the version number and if miss matched, then shell out to your startup script and exit the front end. The first line of your batch file should have a prompt “about to update”, and this will allow time for the FE to shut-down + exit. In fact I suggest using a VBS script since it has a msgbox feature.

Answer (score 2):

I've done the exact same thing, and solved the problem of only re-downloading the frontend when it has changed by using the `xcopy` command with the `/d` switch:

```
xcopy /yqd \\network\frontend.accdb frontend.accdb
```

Xcopy reference: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true

That works, but leaves a small gap in the logic: when someone is using their local copy of the frontend, and you push a new version to the network, and *then* they exit the frontend and run the script again: it won't download the new version because the user's local copy will have a later modification time.

To overcome this, I actually make a copy of the local frontend and start *that* from the script, instead of starting the downloaded copy. That way the downloaded copy retains its original modification time and `xcopy`'s time check works correctly. You do have to train your users though to ignore the local copies of the `accdb` file and only use the script.

Comment: That's an interesting concept. Though if I was going to do something like that, I suppose it'd be easier for me to use a separate text file (possibly even delete the .txt extension), as it would minimize space and reduce the need to copy a file each time. I'll edit the original post with the code I have in my update file.

Comment: @LarrySteeze - actually, if youwere using the `xcopy` `/d` switch, you couldn't use a separate text file. You would need to use the method I gave above. The reason is the `/d` switch doesn't let you specify something like 'If source text file is newer than destination text file, then copy source `accdb` file'. Anyway, I don't think it's a big deal to have two copies of the frontend--they're not that big and any computer running Access does not lack for space.

Comment: You're right. I wouldn't be able to do it with the /d switch. However, someone did give me a good idea in the comments on the original question about using tables to do it.

Comment: @LarrySteeze - cool, I'd be curious to know if that works. If so you could probably post it as an answer here yourself!